# selected table row angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a table with the `ng-class` directive like this:

```
<tbody>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer" class="clickable-row" ng-repeat="firm in device.firmwares" ng-class="{'success': firm.vulnScore<= 4,'warning' :5<= firm.vulnScore,'danger' : 8<=firm.vulnScore}">
          <td>{{firm.fileName}}</td>
          <td>{{firm.extracted}}</td>
          <td>{{firm.vulnScore}}</td>
          <td>{{firm.date}}</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

Basically what it does, is to color the rows depending on the vulnScore value; that works great!, but I need to be able to select the rows, I acomplished that by doing:

```
$('#firm_table').on('click', '.clickable-row', function(event) {
    $(this).addClass('bg-primary').siblings().removeClass('bg-primary');
});
```

and it works...but the only thing that it does is to change the text white, because there's already a color class acting on it... I need to be able to remove the acting class(success,warning or danger) when is selected and put it back when another is selected, i'd be easy if there was just one class...but I don't know how to know which one I had in the first place and how to put it back!

This is what I have:(the first row is selected):

[What I acomplished](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3fhn.png)

and what I what to acomplish is something like:

[What I actually want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7pPX.png)

if someone can help i'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("ctrl" , function($scope){
  $scope.rowIndex = -1;
  $scope.items = [{"name":"ali","score":2},{"name":"reza","score":4},{"name":"amir","score":5},{"name":"amir","score":7},{"name":"amir","score":5},{"name":"asd","score":10},{"name":"jim","score":8},{"name":"babak","score":6},{"name":"vfrt","score":8},{"name":"cdsa","score":7},{"name":"amir","score":10},{"name":"majid","score":3}];
 
  $scope.selectRow = function(index){
      if(index == $scope.rowIndex)
        $scope.rowIndex = -1;
        else
          $scope.rowIndex = index;
    }
  });
```

```css
.success{
  background-color:green;
  }

.warning{
   background-color:yellow;
  }

.danger{
  background-color:red;
  }
.bg-primary{
  color:white;
   background-color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  
  <table>
    {{selectedRow}}
     <tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'success': item.score<= 4,'warning' :5<= item.score,'danger' : 8<=item.score,'bg-primary':rowIndex == $index }" ng-click="selectRow($index)" >
             <td>{{item.name}}</td>
             <td>{{item.score}}</td>
      </tr>
</table>
            
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah...that's basically what i did...but the success,warning and danger classes are already defined by bootstrap, and the background-color is defined in all of them, so when i add a new class, the new one doesn't override the old one, so basically what I end up with is a table row with the same color but white text; I'm posting a picture right now so you can see what's happending!

Comment: I added two pictures, the first one is what I've done so far, the second is what I want to acomplish!

Comment: why don't use custom class for this?

Comment: Yeah...I suppose i could... but I don't see the point... It seems to me that is gonna happen the same thing again...doesn't it?

Comment: I added my custom classes just for the sake of it, and it's all the same, the "background-color" property doesn't change!, it's stuck with the red,yellow or green, I really need help!

Comment: i update my answer and work as you want.please check it.

Comment: So... I run it, and it looked great; i copied the snippet to my actual code and it didn't work...It took me a while to figure out that the bootstrap clases I was using weren't all design to use in a table; so...as you suggested I created custom rules and it works perfectly!, thank you very much man! you got it right!