# Toggle other elements inside ng-repeat on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to apply class by using ng-class and ng-click and this working fine for selected element, but how can I toggle this class in the other elements?

**Improved description**:
*Current behaviour*:
Click on elelement, class applied.
Clik on the other element, this element also class applied.
*Desired behaviour*:
Click on element, class applied.
Other element - class removed.

```
<div ng-repeat="element in ngModel | orderBy:'Field_Order'" class='elementForm' ng-hide="element.IsDeleted">
    <div layout="row" style="width:100%" class="container" ng-mouseover="hovering=true" ng-mouseleave="hovering=false" flex ng-click="selected = !selected">
        <div class="hover-space" ng-class="{'hoveredFormElement':hovering, 'selected':selected}" flex="2" ></div>
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddler link and explain what exactly you want..

Comment: add some code that you have tried

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185017/selected-table-row-angular-js/36185644#36185644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `selected` is inside an isolated scope which is not shared by other items.

One easy solution using index is

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.selected = -1;
  $scope.ngModel = [{
    i: 1
  }, {
    i: 2
  }, {
    i: 3
  }, {
    i: 4
  }];
})
```

```css
.hoveredFormElement {
  color: green;
}
.selected {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    {{selected}}
    <div ng-repeat="element in ngModel | orderBy:'Field_Order'" class='elementForm' ng-hide="element.IsDeleted">
      <div layout="row" style="width:100%" class="container" ng-mouseover="hovering=true" ng-mouseleave="hovering=false" flex ng-click="$parent.selected = $parent.selected == $index ? -1 : $index">
        <div class="hover-space" ng-class="{'hoveredFormElement':hovering, 'selected':selected == $index}" flex="2">{{element}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maintain flag in controller scope and use it over `ng-class`

```
$scope.selected = { index: undefined };
```

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="element in ngModel | orderBy:'Field_Order'" class='elementForm' ng-hide="element.IsDeleted">
    <div layout="row" style="width:100%" class="container" 
      ng-mouseover="hovering = true" 
      ng-mouseleave="hovering = false" 
      flex ng-click="selected.index = !selected">
        <div class="hover-space" 
         ng-class="{'hoveredFormElement':hovering , 'selected':selected.index }" flex="2" ></div>
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```