# ng-repeat not coloring elements properly?

Tags: angularjs, background-color, ng-class

I am stumped on why the fields in my data aren't coloring correctly. I used a simple greater than logic to assign an ng-class of either green, or red. I added debug lines to check that inside the function the values are correct, and the bool is correct, but on the main page items are 'randomly' colored incorrectly. Help?

**I tried several different things on the values, like parseInt() etc with the same results. As Is, no matter what I put inside the function it displays different colors than expected**

```
            <table>
                <th><input class="search" type="text" ng-model="searchKey" placeholder="Character" ng-change="setClickedRow(-1)"></th>
                <th ng-click="setSort('pval1')">
                    <div ng-app="KIdash" ng-controller="controller">
                    Total Matches: {{TotalMatchesFunc()}}
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th ng-click="setSort('pval2')">Wins</th>
                <th ng-click="setSort('pval3')">Losses</th>
                <tbody ng-repeat="ps in PlayerStats | orderBy: sortKey | filter:searchKey">
                    <tr ng-class="{'main-row-selected': $index == selectedRow,'main-row': $index != selectedRow}" ng-click="setClickedRow($index)">
                        <td>{{ps.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{ps.pval1}}</td>

                        <!-- *** THIS IS THE PART THAT ISNT WORKING CORRECTLY *** -->
                        <td ng-class="{'green': GreaterWins({{$index}}),'red': !GreaterWins({{$index}})}">{{ps.pval2}}</td>

                        <td>{{ps.pval3}}</td>
                    </tr>

                    <!-- *** COULD THIS SECOND FUNCTION CALL BE POLLUTING MY RESULTS? *** -->
                    <tr ng-class="{'extra-row-green': GreaterWins({{$index}}),'extra-row-red': !GreaterWins({{$index}})}" ng-show="selectedRow == $index">
                        <td>Detail: {{ps.detail_p1}}</td>
                        <td>Detail: {{ps.detail_p2}}</td>
                        <td>Detail: {{ps.detail_p3}}</td>
                        <td>Detail: {{ps.detail_p4}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>


$scope.GreaterWins = function(z) {
    console.log( "bool " 
        + Boolean($scope.PlayerStats[z].pval2 > $scope.PlayerStats[z].pval3)
        + "   "
        + $scope.PlayerStats[z].pval2 + "vs" + $scope.PlayerStats[z].pval3);

    return Boolean($scope.PlayerStats[z].pval2 > $scope.PlayerStats[z].pval3));
};
```

Comment: Also Tried: 

<td ng-class="{true: 'green', false: 'red'} [GreaterWins({{$index}})]" >{{ps.pval2}}</td>

Comment: The issues seems to revolve around  orderBy: sortKey

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36185017/selected-table-row-angular-js/36185644#36185644

Answer (score 1):

Two things which i feel is creating issue.

1. Instead of passing index in function you should pass variable **ps** as ngRepeat create isolated scope. so some time there is issue.
2. variable **selectedRow** should be object as primitive variables has issue in inheritance and two data binding.

try both things your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really repeat the issue using JSbin, here is the example I made in JSbin.

https://jsbin.com/jadiputoha/edit?html,js,console,output